# delay jquery uploadify process for certain period of time

Tags: php, jquery, uploadify

In **jquery uploadify** plugin, after seleting multiple files ti upload, i want to put a condition for each file in the queue, and if that condition satisfy then only uploading process should continue. otherwise it should stop uploading files. How to check this conditions,

Please help me to get out of this problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[`onComplete()`](http://www.uploadify.com/documentation/events/oncomplete-2/) will fire for each file upload event, and [`uploadifyClearQueue()`](http://www.uploadify.com/documentation/methods/uploadifyclearqueue/) will cancel the uploading process.

That won't delay the uploadify for a certain period of *time* as you put it in the title, but it will enable you to check for a condition and cancel the process if necessary.

Comment: But onComplete()  event will fire after the server script runs. I want to check for a condition before controll goes to server script for upload.

Comment: @shabbir is it a server side condition or a javascript one?

Comment: it is javascript condition. But oncomplete event will be fired after file upload. and i want to check it before before file upload

Comment: I tried using onselect event. i put a confirm box in onselect event, if one confirms from there ,then only process of uploading should continue. But it seems that uploading process doesn't wiat for the confirmation and continue uploading even if someone don't click on the confirmation box

Comment: @shabbir maybe use `onOpen()` and if the confirm returns false, do a `uploadifyClearQueue()`?

Comment: @pekka It doesn't work even in onOpen() event also.I tried ptting condition in all event, but it ddnot work

Comment: @shabbir maybe show the code of your condition. You can edit it into your question

Comment: @pekka It works on onOpen event, but now problem is that i am using jalerts for the confirmation. so it does not work if i am using jconfirm but works with the simple javascript confirmation.

Comment: @shabbir aah, that's your problem right there! As far as I know, there is no way of simulating `confirm()`'s behaviour. You'd have to stop the upload process in any case, and restart it somehow if the confirmation comes back positive